# Avoid overflowing of counter

Tags: programming, c

I have a global uint32_t that keep tracks of used Bytes:

```
uint32_t usedBytes;
int bytesWritten;

byteWritten = myFile.print(data, FILE_WRITE);

if (byteWritten > 0) {
  usedBytes += bytesWritten;
}
```

What happen if usedBytes is close to the maximum (0xFFFFFFFF)? Will incrementing it make it 0, or stuck at 0xFFFFFFFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will wrap around though 0.

```
0xFFFFFFFF + 1 = 0
```

You can add a higher order word to track more data:

```
if (byteWritten > 0) {
    uint32_t newUsed = usedBytes + byteWritten;
    if (newUsed < usedBytes) {
        fourGigsUsed ++;
    }
    usedBytes = newUsed;
}
```

Or you could use `uint64_t` to automate it - however none of the Arduino print routines cope with the `uint64_t` variable type.